# How to compute goodness of fit for a linear model in R

Tags: r, regression, goodness-of-fit

I have fit a linear model using the `lm` function in R...

```
model <- lm(trans.baseline.CD4 ~ hiv$Julian.Date)
```

... and I would like to assess the quality of the model's fit. Is there a function in R that will do this? Alternatively, I found a formula for goodness-of-fit involving the sum of squared residuals given the null and alternative hypotheses, but I don't know how to get these values either. Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all starts with

```
 summary(model)
```

after your fit.  There are numerous commands to assess the fit, test commands, compare alternative models, ... in base R as well as in add-on packages on CRAN.

But you may want to do some reading, for example with Dalgaard's book or another introduction to statistics with R.

Comment: (+1) [Linear Models with R](http://www.maths.bath.ac.uk/~jjf23/LMR/), by Julian J. Faraway is also a good starting point.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there's really no escaping me actually digging down and figuring out what exactly I want to compute. I was just hoping there was some sort of standard first approach to use.

Comment: Yup. _With great freedom comes great responsibility._ It is easy to just mechanically compute something. It may be much harder to come up something meaningful. Damn _No Free Lunch_ theorem again...

Answer (score 1):

You should probably take a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181025/goodness-of-fit-functions-in-r